# Python Error : [ZeroDivisionError: division by zero]

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a questions regarding one of my python codes. I am still learning so please don't mind any mistakes. The assignment is to calculate how old someone is in normal years, and in venus years.

Normal years was quite easy, but venus years is a bit harder.

```
a = input("What is your name? ")
b = input("What is your birth year? ")
c = 2019
d = 0.62

# calculating age
try:
    e = int(c) - int(b)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    e = 0

# calculating age in venus years
try:
    f = int(e) / int(d)
except ZeroDivisionError:
  f = 1


print('Dear',a,','' in 2019 your age will be ',e,'.',sep='')
print('And your age is',f,'in Venusyears.')
```

The problem that I have is that is will always see f as 0. But if I don't do:

```
    f = int(e) / int(d)
except ZeroDivisionError:
  f = 1
```

It will give me a ZeroDivisionError due to e not being a number (yet).

Can someone explain to me how to solve this issue?

Hope to hear from you!

Kind regards,

Comment: `d` is `0.62`.  That's a floating point value.  `int(d)` is an integer, and its value is `0`.  So it makes no sense to divide by `int(d)`.  You need to re-think what you're trying to do.  Either keep it as float, or change its value, or get rid of the divide completely.

Answer (score 5):

`ZeroDivisionError` is not caused by `e` not being a number. It caused by trying to divide a number by `int(d)`, because `int(d)` is zero.

`d` is a float with the value 0.62. If you cast that to an integer, you get zero.

You can divide by the float itself:

```
f = int(e) / d
```

That will give you another float. If you want that as an integer, you can cast it to one:

```
f = int(int(e) / d)
```

This will not cause a `ZeroDivisionError`, because `d` is explicitly nonzero in your code.

Answer (score 0):

So in your calculations `d = 0.62` and `int(0.62) == 0`. So at the end you always defide by 0. And if I understand correctly you use `int()` to make sure that your age value is an integer (i.e. 17 years 2 months and thre days is 17 years). To achieve that you should only use `int` at the end result for example:

```py
a = input("What is your name? ")
b = input("What is your birth year? ")
c = 2019
d = 0.62

# calculating age
try:
    e = int(c) - int(b)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    e = 0

# calculating age in venus years
try:
    f = e / d
except ZeroDivisionError:
  f = 1
f = int(f)

print('Dear',a,','' in 2019 your age will be ',e,'.',sep='')
print('And your age is',f,'in Venusyears.')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = 0.62
```

Initially you are taking d has a floating value.

```
f = int(e) / int(d)
```

here your are type casting the d value float(0.62) to int(0). This Division operation throw the exception.. 
Solution:

```
f = int(e) / d
```